# Apply conditions from Master Page to multiple asp child pages for Control Level Security in Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, wcf-security

I have ASP.Net web form application including Master Pages, base page (inherited class) and User Header controls. I want to apply server side control security in master or some global page, i will check from database in my master or global page that this page has either add permissions or not, if not i will disable the add button in the child page, same for other buttons.

Can you please suggest me what is the best way to do so? 
I am unable to access child class from parent class as per the principle and same for the master page, which cannot access child page, find the image attached for more clarification.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use FindControl to locate the Button in the ContentPlaceHolder of the Master Page and then disable it.

```
Button btn = ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("Button1") as Button;

btn.Enabled = false;
```

Remember that the Page Load of the Master Page is executed AFTER the Page Load of the page using the Master. If you do not know this it can give unexpected results.